# Where is the source code for maven-properties-plugin?

Tags: maven, properties

The `maven-properties-plugin` sources used to be hosted on Codehaus (http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin), but I cannot find the new home for the sources anywhere.

Does anyone know if they have been migrated somewhere?  I checked the CodeHaus github repository, but can't find them there.

The last known version was `1.0-alpha2`.

Comment: The documentation is back online: See http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codehaus project has been moved to another location at [www.mojohaus.org](http://www.mojohaus.org/), they also have a GitHub home page at: https://github.com/mojohaus/.

The sources your are looking for is at https://github.com/mojohaus/properties-maven-plugin

Comment: The project has not ended but the hosting services and infrastructure services. So the projects need to move to new locations. http://github.com/mojohaus/ is the correct home...Yes not all plugin documentations are online yet but we are working on it....

Comment: sorry - very bad choice of words. Rock on. Its an important source :)

Comment: Apache properties-maven-plugin is no more under active development. There is a new fork created here: https://github.com/Mikhail2048/properties-maven-plugin