# Has the source code for aspectj-maven-plugin been lost?

Tags: maven, aspectj-maven-plugin

This is a bit of a followup to my a [previous codehaus question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30811993/827480).  This time, I'm looking for the sources for the aspectj-maven-plugin.

I've tried searching github.com, but the closest thing I found is a [personal fork](https://github.com/haskovec/aspectj-maven-plugin) as of v1.7.

Has all the source code for the plugin been lost now that codehaus has shut down?  I haven't found anything helpful on the mojohaus site either.

Answer (score 1):

The mojo project found a new home: http://www.mojohaus.org/, the
sources can be found at https://github.com/mojohaus

Comment: I already searched github.com/mojohaus but don't see them there anywhere. Am I missing something?  I even scrolled thru all 4 pages of repos.   Additionally, the link on the mojohaus.org/plugins page for aspectj-maven-plugin is a dead link.

Comment: Mojohaus has a dump of the codehaus sources. They're still porting plugins one by one. This situation gives the opportunity to do some cleanup and drop unused plugins. I'm sure this one will return. Use https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mojohaus-dev to ask for the plugin to be available again.